# How to change backgroundColor in react native modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change backgroundColor in Modal

Now background color Transparent or white

```
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  visible={modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {}}
>
   <View>
     <Text> Hello<Text/>
   </View>
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            visible={modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {}}
          >
<View style={{flex:1 , backgroundColor:'red'}}>
<Text> Hello<Text/>
</View>
</Modal>
```

you can try this and see if it works